# How to maintain ListView position when using the new Loader APIs?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-support-library, android-cursor

In Honeycomb the [Loader](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html) APIs were introduced as the proper way to provide data to an application by doing the heavy lifting on a background thread.  In my application I'm working to replace all my `Cursor`s with `Loader`s that return `Cursor`s.  Since `Cursor.requery()` is depreciated now, it is recommended to just call `restartLoader` and allow the work to again be done on a background thread and then `changeCursor` when it returns in `onLoadFinished`.

All of this works wonderfully except that the ListView doesn't maintain it's scroll position when I want to requery the data, using `Cursor.requery()` this used to work because it was the same Cursor instance with updated data.

How can I refresh my Loader without loosing the scroll position?

Comment: You could use `getScrollX()` and `getScrollY()` to cache it before you refresh, and then manually set it again.  I'm not sure if this would result in visual flashing or other unpleasantness.  :-/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Loader` class by itself doesn't know when the dataset changes and is implementation specific to `CursorLoader` currently.  Now inside my application the data I needed to refresh is inside a local SQLite database (no ContentProvider) so I had to modify the `CursorLoader` to use my local database instead, as Dianne Hackborne mentioned on the [developer group](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/27e52a977327ef76/0a2b3f086cd9b380?lnk=gst&q=CursorLoader#0a2b3f086cd9b380).

Unfortunately just returning a Cursor from loadInBackground doesn't allow the `ContentObserver` to properly notify the Loader when the data changes, this is because `AbstractCursor` only calls `notifyChanged()` when `requery()` is called on the Cursor.

Since the `ContentObserver` will never notify the `Loader` that the data has changed, I ended up calling `Loader.onContentChanged()` myself as needed. At this point it everything seems to be working but I'll update this answer if any significant issues arrise.

Answer (score 1):

You must just do not create a new adapter in each Loaders loading; I mean..

```
@Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<NotificationItem>> loader, List<NotificationItem> notifications) {
        // We must do it in this way to not losing listview scroll position after a reload.
        if(mAdapter==null) {
            mAdapter = new HomeUserActivityListAdapter(getActivity(), notifications);
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        }else{
            mAdapter.refill(notifications);
        }
    }
```

And in you adapter create a method to items refill

```
public void refill(List<NotificationItem> notifications) {
    mNotificationsList.clear();
    mNotificationsList.addAll(notifications);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And that's all, it will maintain your scroll position exactly :-)